# Translate Java code into Jython code

Tags: java, python-2.7, jython-2.7

The code below is written in Java. It has been shortened to simplify the time required for an answer. The full code takes a screenshot and copies it to the clipboard. (Source: http://www.coderanch.com/t/333565/GUI/java/BufferedImage-System-Clipboard)

I am trying to use it in a Jython 2.7 program. I'm confused on how to alter this code because of all the private classes involved.

```
 public class ClipboardImage implements ClipboardOwner {
     public ClipboardImage() {
      try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Dimension screenSize  = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Rectangle screen = new Rectangle( screenSize );
        BufferedImage i = robot.createScreenCapture( screen );
        TransferableImage trans = new TransferableImage( i );
        Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        c.setContents( trans, this );
    }
    catch ( AWTException x ) {
        x.printStackTrace();
        System.exit( 1 );
    }
 }

    public static void main( String[] arg ) {
         ClipboardImage ci = new ClipboardImage();
    }

     public void lostOwnership( Clipboard clip, Transferable trans ) {
         System.out.println( "Lost Clipboard Ownership" );
     }

     private class TransferableImage implements Transferable {

         Image i;

         public TransferableImage( Image i ) {
             this.i = i;
         }

         public Object getTransferData( DataFlavor flavor ) 
         throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
             if ( flavor.equals( DataFlavor.imageFlavor ) && i != null ) {
                 return i;
             }
             else {
                 throw new UnsupportedFlavorException( flavor );
             }
         }

         public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
             DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[ 1 ];
             flavors[ 0 ] = DataFlavor.imageFlavor;
             return flavors;
         }

         public boolean isDataFlavorSupported( DataFlavor flavor ) {
             DataFlavor[] flavors = getTransferDataFlavors();
             for ( int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++ ) {
                 if ( flavor.equals( flavors[ i ] ) ) {
                     return true;
                 }
             }

             return false;
         }
     }
 }
```

I've been able to translate it to the following code:

```
robot = Robot()
screenSize  = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()
screen = Rectangle(screenSize)
i = robot.createScreenCapture(screen)
flavors = DataFlavor.imageFlavor.equals(i)
trans = Transferable.getTransferDataFlavors(flavors)
c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()
c.setContents(trans, trans)
```

However, I'm getting a TypeError:

> getTransferDataFlavors(): self arg can't be coerced to java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable.

I'm struggling with the part of assigning the `dataFlavor.imageFlavor` to my image, and then making it transferable, so I can set it to clipboard contents.

Comment: This is not a translation service. Try it on your own and you will learn much more at the end.

Comment: Ok, with your changes I voted to reopen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
class TransferableImage(Transferable) :

     def __init__(self, image) :
             if not isinstance(image, Image) :
                      raise IllegalArgumentException("Parameter must be of type java.awt.Image")
             self.image = image

     def getTransferData(self, flavor) :
             if not isinstance(flavor, DataFlavor) :
                      raise IllegalArgumentException("Parameter must be of type java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor")
             if not flavor.equals(DataFlavor.imageFlavor) : 
                      raise UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor)
             return self.image

     def getTransferDataFlavors(self) :
             return [DataFlavor.imageFlavor];

     def isDataFlavorSupported(self, flavor) :
             if not isinstance(flavor, DataFlavor) :
                      raise IllegalArgumentException("Parameter must be of type java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor")
             return flavor in getTransferFlavors()

class ClipboardImage(ClipboardOwner) :

     def __init__(self) :
             robot = Robot()
             toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
             screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize()
             screen = Rectangle(screenSize)
             image = robot.createScreenCapture(screen)
             trans = TransferableImage(image)
             clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard()
             clipboard.setContents(trans, self)

     def lostOwnership(self, clip, trans) :
             print("Lost Clipboard Ownership")


ci = ClipboardImage()
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why would my answer get a downvote?